# MySQL : combine multiple row into one row

Tags: mysql, sql, row

I have a mysql table with this :

[image]

In table 1, i have 3 column : Bidang, Keahlian, Nilai. 
In table result in the coloumn saran i want to combine keahlian based on bidang, but keahlian taken if nilai > 0. The result like this :

[image]

So, please help me to make this.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Bidang,GROUP_CONCAT(Keahlian SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM table_1 
WHERE Nilai>0
GROUP BY Bidang
```

Comment: If i want to input a Group_Concat in conditional statement. how to i make it?

Comment: what you mean by add this function?

Comment: your code doesn't work, you are doing the mistake in your query not a `SEPARATER` you should use this  `SEPARATOR`

Comment: Also you forgot "as Saran" to make it look like the question author wanted.

Comment: @jmail sorry spelling mistake

Answer (score 1):

***like this:***

```
SELECT Bidang,GROUP_CONCAT(Keahlian SEPARATOR ',') As Saran
FROM Table_1
WHERE Nilai>0
GROUP BY Bidang
```

Comment: If i want to input a Group_Concat in conditional statement. how to i make it?

Answer (score 0):

You can user bewlow query

```
SELECT bidang,GROUP_CONCAT(kealian) as saran
FROM table1 
WHERE nilai>=0
GROUP BY bidang
```